# Extract all text between third to last and last period

Tags: r, regex

I have text that looks like:

```
txt <- Name, Name. Title. Pub. Year; Details.
```

I want to extract only Pub.

I can extract year and details using:

```
gsub(".*\\.(.*)\\..*", "\\1", txt)
```

How can extract everything between the third to last and second to last period (just Pub) in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `sub` (since you need to perform a single search and replace operation) the following way:

```
txt <-"Name, Name. Title. Pub. Year; Details."
sub(".*\\.([^.]*)(?:\\.[^.]*){2}$", "\\1", txt)
# => [1] " Pub"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/8QsaSi).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\\.` - a `.`
- `([^.]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `.`
- `(?:\\.[^.]*){2}` - 2 consecutive sequences of

  - `\\.` - a `.`
  - `[^.]*` - any 0+ chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.